# How to use dao method in BroadcastReceiver MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have app with MVVM architecture and need to pick a random word from database in my BroadcastReceiver so as to show it in notification. Is it ok to use viewModel instance inside BroadcastReceiver and how can I use it there or should I call it from fragment somehow? How can I pass it to BroadcastReceiver in this case?

BroadcastReceiver:

```
class AlarmReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver() {
    //private val viewModel: DictionaryViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        // viewModel.getRandomWordForNotification()

        val notificationIntent = Intent(context, ListFragment::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK 
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channelID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Reminder")
            .setContentText("word - translation")
            .setAutoCancel(true) 
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent
            )
            .build()

        val notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(123, builder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, do you want to show a notification when the app is in the foreground right?

Comment: No, I want to schedule my notification so as it shows in the same time every day. So the app is not always in the foreground.

Comment: No, you can't get viewmodel in AlarmReceiver. But you have context in onReceive, so you can get your DB and DAO instance right there.

Comment: But will not it ruin MVVM principle?